# Android Parent View: How do I reduce by the size of the Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've set up a new android Toolbar with:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

The toolbar appears correctly at the top of the screen.  The problem I'm having is that the top of the background image for the remainder of the app screen is being covered over by toolbar.  I need to reduce the height of the container that holds the background image by the height of the toolbar in my layout file but am not having any luck.

The toolbar is showing correctly.  It has an image as a background.

Here is the main.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/big_wave"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_skypic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Keeping background as transparent in the toolbar will also solve your problem right?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the height of the image yourself, can't you? Or you can set the tool baar background as translucent or transparent.

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

Comment: The toolbar background is set to a drawable image and displays properly.  It's as if the parent view does not see or recognize the height of the toolbar.
If the total vertical screen height is 100 and the toolbar vertical height is 10, I'm trying to find a way for the screen background drawable to show within the remaining 90 height.

Comment: Can you post the way uou implement what you said?

Because you can always use layouts of respective sizes and paint them in whatever color you want.

Comment: I will post now up above in original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:layout_below` property

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <com.example.sample.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output.[image]

You can see below toolbar there is sliding layout tabs

Comment: Tried this and same result...the toolbar covers over the top of the main background image.